# foreign key not migrate. I have some problems with migrations. I already well migrate company table

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-7, artisan-migrate

This my code

```
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->text('second_name');
            $table->string('emp_company')->unsigned();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('emp_company')->references('company_name')->on('companies');
        });
```

---

here my error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `phone` varchar(255) not null,' at line 1 (SQL: create table `employees` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `first_name` varchar(255) not null, `second_name` text not null, `emp_company` varchar(255) unsigned not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `phone` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

im stuck with this ..looking for sup
Thank you.

Comment: Strings can't be unsigned, only number fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your problem in this line:

```
 $table->string('emp_company')->unsigned();
```

unsigned is used only for numeric columns, to force only positive numbers,
there is no UNSIGNED for string column, it's meanless

just remove ->unsigned() and your code should work ....